# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'timeout'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have got this code here

```
site = urllib.request.urlopen('http://omegle.com/start')
id = fmtId( site.read() )
print(id)
req = urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://omegle.com/events', urllib.parse.urlencode( {'id':id}))
print('finding')
```

And this

```
site = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
rec = site.read()
```

And I am getting this error

```
File "C:\Users\...\script.py", line 74, in <module>
omegleConnect()
File "C:\Users\...\script.py", line 70, in omegleConnect
listenServer(id,req)
File "C:\Users\...\script.py", line 32, in listenServer
site = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 156, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 460, in open
req.timeout = timeout
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

I'm not experienced with python AT ALL so please explain it simple to me if you like.
I don't actually know what is going wrong in my code right now. If you need anything else from my code, or more details, just ask.

Comment: `urllib.request.urlretrieve` returns a tuple and you are passing a tuple to `urllib.request.urlopen`

Comment: you are passing a tuple by accident

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import urllib 
site = urllib.urlopen('http://omegle.com/start')
id_ = site.read()
print(id_)
```

Can you try this codes. When i try to run this codes, they are working. I guess urllib hasn't got property like request.

Answer (score 2):

The second call you make to urlopen you are giving it a tuple, which is an immutable list of something like this

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

It does not have properties, and the code is trying to access a "timeout" property on that tuple. It is likely you mean to send urlopen a url that is inside the req object, not the full tuple. If you are just starting out in Python (and even if not), you might want to check out the requests library at
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ which is very easy to use and well documented.